# Square of a matrix as coefficients for a system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

small question I'm having a disagreement with a classmate over - it's a question in a book:

Let $A$ be a square matrix $n \times n$

Prove or disprove:

If the system $A\underline{x}=\underline{b}$ has infinite solutions then $A^2\underline{x}=\underline{b}$ also has infinite solutions.

I say it's true, because if $A\underline{x}=\underline{b}$ has infinite solutions then $A$ must be singular and therefore contains at least one row of zeroes somewhere, so its square must also contain a row of zeroes in the same places and so the second system must also have infinite solutions.

The book says it's false and doesn't elaborate or supply a proof - my classmate agrees with the book. What do you guys think?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is possible that $Ax=b$ has a solution and $A^2x=b$ has none. A simple example is a $2 \times 2$ matrix of zeroes except for the upper right. Then $A^2 = 0$. Choose some $b$ so that $Ax=b$ has a solution.

Comment: If $A$ is singular, its _row-reduced echelon form_ will have a row of zeros, but the original matrix need not.

Answer (score 0):

The book is right. Take $A$ as the matrix with all entries $0$, except for the right upper corner, with entry $1$. Then $A$ is a nilpotent $n\times n$ matrix with $A\neq 0$ and $A^2=0$. Then let $x=(0,0,\ldots ,r)^t$ for $r\in \mathbb{R}$, $r\neq 0$, and $b=(r,0,0,\ldots ,0)^t$. Then $Ax=b$, with infinitely many $x$, but $A^2x=0\neq b$, so that $A^2x=b$ has no solution.

As to your argument. If $A$ is singular, it need not contain a row of zeroes somewhere. Take the matrix $A$ where every entry is equal to $1$. Then $\det(A)=0$ for every $n\ge 2$, but every row is $(1,1,\ldots ,1)$.